# How can my integraded terminal automatically cd into the directory of the currently active file?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm pretty new to Visual Studio Code and am used to a nice feature from my previous IDE. That feature had the integrated terminal follow the active file into its directory, at all times. So when I switched to viewing another file in my IDE, the integrated terminal would change its cwd to that new file's directory.

I'm aware of the [Terminal Here Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.vscode-terminal-here) and the context menu option:

[image: vs-code context-menu: Open in Integrated Terminal]

The problem with both is, that they require action on my part, i.e. using a shortcut or the context-menu respectively. I want the terminal to just change into the active file's directory, whenever I switch to another file.

How can I achieve this with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Also relevant: [related Terminal Here issue](https://github.com/Tyriar/vscode-terminal-here/issues/9)